# PHP Binary Tree Pairing

Tags: php, algorithm, binary-tree

I would like to ask for some help regarding pairing of binary tree. Consider the following binary tree:

```
                          A
                          |
                  ------------------
                  |                |
                  B                C
                  |                |
            ----------        ----------
            |        |        |        |
            F        D        G        Z
            |                          |
     ----------------          ----------------
     |              |          |              |
     W              Y          M              N
     |              |          |              |
  ----------  ----------   ----------  ----------
  |        |  |        |   |        |  |        |
  X        E  O        P   R        Q  S        T
```

How to perform "center pairing" in this binary tree?

These are the possible center pairs for each node:

> - **Center Pair of A:** B - C, F - Z, D - G, W - N, Y - M, X - T, E - S, O - Q, P - R
> - **Center Pair of B:** F - D
> - **Center Pair of C:** G - Z
> - **Center Pair of F:** W - Y, X - P, E - O
> - **Center Pair of Z:** M - N, R - T, Q - S

Below is my code. But it only works up to the 2nd level. I wanted to make a dynamic function--something that I can pass what level is "X" in the tree then the function can find if "T" is available.

```php
  function GetNodeLevel($accUname) {
    $x = 1;
    $level = 0;
    $placement = $accUname; 
    while($x > 0) {
      $placement = getPlacement($placement);
      if(strlen($placement) > 0) {
        $level++;
      } else {
        $x=0;
      }
    }

    return $level;
  }

  // 2ND LEVEL PARENT OF THE NODE
  function FindMy2ndLevelParent($accUname) {
    require('connection.php');

    $my_level = GetNodeLevel($accUname) - 1;

    for($x=1;$x <= $my_level;$x++) {
      $accUname = getPlacement($accUname); 
    }
    return $accUname;    
  }

  // OUTER MOST CENTER PAIR IN 2ND LEVEL
  function FindMy2ndLevelOuterCenterPair($accUname,$side) {
    require('connection.php');

    $my_uname = $accUname;
    $my_side = $side;
    $my_level = GetNodeLevel($accUname) - 1;

    for($x=1;$x <= $my_level;$x++) {
      $accUname = getPlacement($accUname);  
    }

   for($y=1;$y <= $my_level;$y++) {
      if ($side == 'left'){
       $tree = genealogy($accUname);
       $accUname = $tree['right_side']; 
      } else {
       $tree = genealogy($accUname);
       $accUname = $tree['left_side']; 
      }      
    }

    return $accUname;
  }

  // INNER MOST CENTER PAIR IN 2ND LEVEL
  function FindMy2ndLevelInnerCenterPair($accUname,$side) {
    require('connection.php');

    $my_uname = $accUname;
    $my_side = $side;
    $my_level = GetNodeLevel($accUname) - 1;

    for($x=1;$x <= $my_level;$x++) {
      $accUname = getPlacement($accUname);  
    }

    for($y=1;$y <= $my_level;$y++) {
      if ($y == 1 && $side == 'left') {
        $tree = genealogy($accUname);
        $accUname = $tree['left_side'];        
      } else if ($y == 1 && $side == 'right') {
        $tree = genealogy($accUname);
        $accUname = $tree['right_side'];        
      } else if ($y > 1 && $side == 'right')  {
        $tree = genealogy($accUname);
        $accUname = $tree['left_side'];                 
      } else if ($y > 1 && $side == 'left')  {
        $tree = genealogy($accUname);
        $accUname = $tree['right_side'];                 
      }       
    }

    return $accUname;
  }
```

Also my function has a predefined position where to go on the other side of the tree. But this is not a smart solution since if I want to get its center pair on the 3rd level, I have to define its path.

Comment: Your example binary tree is completely symmetric. What should happen if it is not? Could you add some examples?

Comment: @ggorlen did you find any solution?