# PHP Array Relation

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, gojs

[image]

I want to make a binary tree by connecting the REV column with the KEY column with ROOT KEY = 2 and delete the arrays that are not related to KEY 2. Thank you

[image]

I want to change the root tree to the image in the blue box, and delete all data that is not related to the data in the blue box.

i have this code for all result data, how to filter data only showing KEY=2 as root

```
function get_rev() {
    $id =  session()->get('user')['id'];
    $Array = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
            ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, level')
            ->where('reveral !=', '-')
            ->get()->getResultArray();
            
    //dd($Array);
    return $Array;
}
```

The following is the data array of all results

```
[{"key":"1","rev":"2","name":"JUNO MARPAUNG","address":"JL. SISINGAMANGARAJA NO. 37 YOGYAKARTA , DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"1"},{"key":"2","rev":"6","name":"EDDY PROYEKSI PT.","address":"GEDUNG STC SENAYAN LANTAI 2 RUANG 89 JL.ASIA AFRIKA PINTU IX GELORA SENAYAN, Kel. Gelora, Kec. Tanah Abang, Kota Adm. Jakarta Pusat, Prop. DKI Jakart","picture":"1688217815_1ddffa097a9bb623c213.png","level":"1"},{"key":"3","rev":"12","name":" HENKEL INDONESIEN ,PTNOM","address":"NISSI BINTARO CAMPUS LANTAI 3JL. TEGAL ROTAN RAYA NO.78KEL. SAWAH BARU, KEC. TANGERANGBANTEN","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"4","rev":"1","name":" IFB INDONESIA, PTNOM","address":"SENTRA BISNIS ARTHA GADING BLOK A7-D NO.10JL. BOULEVARD ARTHA GADING, JAKARTA UTARAON BEHALF IFL INTERNATIONAL FREIGHT LINES LIMITED","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"5","rev":"2","name":" METRO PEARL INDONESIA O\/B GLOBALINK WORLDWIDE LTD","address":"JLN. PRAMUKA RAYA NO.18 KM 0.99DS. BUNDER KEC.JATILUHUR - PURWAKARTAJAWA BARAT - INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"6","rev":"6","name":" PRIMAHOTEL MANAJEMEN INDONESIA.PT","address":"JL. GUNUNG SAHARI RAYA RUKO MARINATAMA BLOKA NO.26-27 JAKARTA UTARA 14420","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"7","rev":"5","name":" TPIL LOGISTICS ,PT","address":"JL. CUMI NO. 31 RT.004 RW.008 TANJUNG PRIOK JAKARTA UTARA,DKI JAKARTA - 14310INDONESIATAX ID: 01.967.361.5-046.000","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"8","rev":"5","name":" UNGARAN SARI GARMENTS PTNOM","address":"JL. P. DIPONEGORO NO.235. P.O.BOX 108GENUK UNGARAN BARAT, SEMARANG,JAWA TENGAH 50512, INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"9","rev":"12","name":"100 PERCENT CONCEPT ASIA-PACIFIC LTD","address":"OFFICE TOWER, ITC CEMPAKA MAS 7TH FLOOR, ROOM #15BJL. LET JEND. SOEPRAPTO JAKARTAINDONESIA - 10640","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"10","rev":"13","name":"3S PRIME CONTINENTAL - 3SPC CARGO, PT.","address":"INTERNATIONAL FREIGHT FORWARDERPHONE: +62 21 5436 0108FAX: +62 21 544 7483","picture":"default.jpg","level":"2"},{"key":"11","rev":"1","name":"3S PRIME CONTINENTAL PTNOM","address":"RUKO DUTA INDAH ALPHA B-3JL. PETA SELATAN - KALIDERES, JAKARTA BARAT 11840TEL: +6221-54360108TAX ID: 03.017.325.6-085.000","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"12","rev":"13","name":"4EVER TRANSINDO PTNOM","address":"JL.JATIWARINGIN RAYA NO24 BLK.MRT.8 CIPINANG JAKARTA ID 13620TELP\/FAX: (62-21)29474874\/29474873TAX ID NO.:03.257.404.8.005.000","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"13","rev":"6","name":"7SEAS LOGISTICS GROUP LIMITED","address":"MENARA KUNINGAN, LEVEL 30JL.HR RASUNA SAID BLOK X-7 KAV.5KARET KUNINGANSOUTH JAKARTA 12940. INDONESIATEL.: (021) 29553679 FAX.: (021) 29553678","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"15","rev":"11","name":"A.W. FABER-CASTELL INDONESIA, PT.","address":"JL. RAYA NAROGONG, PANGKALAN IBBANTAR GEBANG, BEKASI INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"16","rev":"7","name":"ABADI PERKASA SUKSES LOGISTIK,PT","address":"JALAN OTISTA RAYA NO. 458 CAWANGJAKARTA TIMUR 13330 - INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"17","rev":"7","name":"ABD SEJAHTERA, CV.","address":"JL. GANG BLOK KARANG DEWA RT.011\/RW.003DESA MAYUNG, KEC. GUNUNG JATI, KAB. CIREBON","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"18","rev":"8","name":"ABR LOGISTIK INDONESIA, PT","address":"JALAN SENTRA BISNIS ARTHA GADING BLOK A7C NO.28KELAPA GADING BARAT,KELAPA GADINGJAKARTA UTARA 14240,INDONESIATEL : +62 21 4587 8932 FAX : +62 21 45","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"19","rev":"8","name":"ACC EXPRESS,PT","address":"PHONE : 021 2903 2488","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"20","rev":"11","name":"ACE INTERNASIONAL LOGISTIKS, PT.","address":"JL ARTERI MANGGA DUA RAYA, GBC- D\"15, JAKARTA - 14430, INDONESIAPH: +62 21 6122403FAX: +62 21 6122404","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"21","rev":"1489","name":"ACE MULTITRANS CARGO, PT.","address":"JAMKRINDO BLDG RM703JL.ANGKASA BLOK B9 KAV 6KEMAYORAN,JAKARTA 10720 INDONESIA ","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"22","rev":"1489","name":"ACE MULTITRANS CARGO,PTNOM","address":"THE MANSION BOUGENVILLETOWER FONTANA ZONE 2, 37 FLOOR, I2-M2JL. TREMBESI BLOCK D, KEMAYORANJAKARTA UTARA 14410 - INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"23","rev":"1641","name":"ACT LOGISTICS INTERNATIONAL PT","address":"JL. YOS SUDARSO KAV 89MITRA SUNTER BLDG 12TH FL-06 SUNTER 14350, JAKARTA INDONESIA ","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"24","rev":"3","name":"ACT TRANS INTERNATONAL. PT","address":"WISMA MITRA SUNTER 9TH SUITE 904JL. YOS SUDARSO KAV 89 SUNTER JAYA JAKARTA UTARA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"25","rev":"3","name":"ACTLINK MARINE TRANSPORT, PT.","address":"MITRA SUNTER BUILDING 12TH FL., SUITE 02,MITRA SUNTER BOULEVARD BLOK C-2,JL. YOS SUDARSO KAV. 89, ","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"26","rev":"1641","name":"ADETEX, PT.","address":"JL. DAYANG SUMBI NO. 4-6BANDUNG 40132 INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"27","rev":"9","name":"ADETEXNOM PT.","address":"JL. DAYANG SUMBI NO. 4-6BANDUNG 40132 INDNESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"28","rev":"9","name":"ADHI JAYA METALINDO,PT ","address":"KP. CADAS RT. 005 RW. 002SEPATAN, TANGERANG 15520, BANTENINDONESIA ","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"29","rev":"28","name":"ADHIKA MAJU MANDIRI,PT","address":"JALAN EDAM II NO. 15ATANJUNG PRIOK JAKARTA UTARATELP. (021) 43938867\/ 43924570-72FAX : 021-43924569","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"30","rev":"28","name":"ADI TRANS LOGISTICS,PT","address":"RUKO ISLAMIC CENTRE GATE 2JL. KRAMAT JAYA NO. 22MJAKARTA UTARA 14260-INDONESIAT: 021-43932561","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"33","rev":"19","name":"ADIRA SEMESTA INDUSTRY PT.","address":"JL.BIHBUL RAYA NO.73BANDUNG INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"1489","rev":"10","name":"POU CHEN INDONESIA","address":"KAMPUNG GARDU RT.06\/RW.01 TAMBAK KIBINSERANG BANTEN, INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"1641","rev":"10","name":"PT XIN CHENG DA","address":"JL. RAYA SERANG, KP. CIREWED SUKADAMAI\/CIKUPA KAB. TANGERANG","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"2025","rev":"4","name":"PT. POU CHEN INDONESA","address":"KAMPUNG GARDU RT 06\/01 TAMBAKKIBIN SERANG BANTENSERANG, 42185INDONESIA","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"2047","rev":"4","name":"PT. RHENUS LOGISTICS INDONESIA","address":"18 OFFICE PARK TOWER A UNIT 10 C JLTB SIMATUPANG NO. 18KEBAGUSAN PASAR MINGGUJAKARTA, INDONESIA 12520","picture":"default.jpg","level":"3"},{"key":"2778","rev":"19","name":"ZIMMOAH MARINE TRANS,PT","address":"KIRANA COMMERCIAL AVENUEJL. KIRANA AVENUE 2 BLOK D2 NO.10-11KELAPA GADING, JAKARTA UTARA 14240IND","picture":"default.jpg","level":"2"}]
```

I am trying to fetch data from root and then child with the following code

```
function get_revs() {
    
    $id =  session()->get('user')['id'];
    $db = model('AppModel', false);
    $db->setTable('mp_members');
    $db->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_reveral_' . $id);
    $db->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_reveral_' . $id .'`
        (
            `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `rev` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
            `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `picture` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            `level` int(1) NOT NULL
        )'
    );
                
    $boss = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
            ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, level')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get()->getResultArray();
            
    model('CrudModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->insert($boss[0]);
    
    $dt = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
        ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, level')
        ->where('reveral !=', '-')
        ->where('reveral', $id)
        ->get();
    
    if( $dt->getNumRows() != 0 ) {
        foreach( $dt->getResultArray() as $row ) {
            $data[]=model('CrudModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->insert($row);   
        }
        /// how do i get the following data after this procedure
    }
    
    $dm = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->get()->getResultArray();
    
    //dd( $dm, $data );
    return $dm; 

}
```

[image: generate a chart like this]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we prefer text and code over images, [edit] your question and replace the images with textual information and show the algorithm you've done so far ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58603702/367456), see also [mre]). With that ask a concrete question. If you're looking on how to do this in general in PHP, use the search instead of posting a new question. Q&A material should exist.

Comment: you could walk through each array item, checking the 'rev' value in recursive manner until you get to the rev=2, saving list of 'key' number per each item on the way, if you do not get to the rev=2, then you have list of key's which none of them is child of key=2, you can remove them from original array, if you end up with rev=2, then you have list of key's which are all child's of key=2, you could keep these in separated array for fast lookup, in the end you will have filtered array of only key=2 and child's, with decent performance

Comment: An easier way to get the data I want is it better to make a query in mysql or filter the data from the results of all results, I've added the code and array to the post

Comment: yea that is better, here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy

Comment: What's currently not working as expected?

Comment: So far it's been working fine, but with this method it seems to work quite slowly, if only there was code that could make it faster to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Below code can give solution for data i need

```
private function get_reveral() {
    
    $id =  session()->get('user')['id'];
    $db = model('AppModel', false);
    $db->setTable('mp_members');
    $db->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_reveral_' . $id);
    $db->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_reveral_' . $id .'`
        (
            `key` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `rev` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
            `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `picture` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            `level` int(1) NOT NULL
        )'
    );
                
    $rev = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
            ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, email, level')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get()->getResultArray();
            
    model('CrudModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->insert($rev[0]);
    
    $dt = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
        ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, email, level')
        ->where('reveral', $id)
        ->get();
        
    $key = null;
    if( $dt->getNumRows() != 0 ) {
        foreach( $dt->getResultArray() as $row ) {
            model('CrudModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->insert($row);   
            $key[] = $row['key'];
        }
        
    }
    
    if($key == null) { 
        $da = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->get()->getResultArray();
    } else {
        $da = $this->get_next_child($id, $key);
    }
    
    return $da;

}


private function get_next_child( $id , $array = null ) {
    
    foreach( $array as $row ) {
        $da[] = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('mp_members')
                ->select('id as key, reveral as rev, name, address, picture, email, level')
                ->where('reveral', $row)
                ->get()->getResultArray();
    }
    
    $key = null;
    if($da != null) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $da as $row){
            if($row != null ) {
                foreach( $row as $val){
                    model('CrudModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->insert($val);
                    $key[] = $val['key'];
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    
    if($key == null ) {
        $dc = model('AppModel', false)->setTable('temp_reveral_' . $id)->get()->getResultArray();
    } else {
        $dc = $this->get_next_child($id, $key);
    }
    
    return $dc;
    
}
```

[image: The tree image below shows root changes according to member login sessions]

[image: when changing session member login]